# Custom TextBox that accepts Decimal in C#.NET

Tags: c#, windows, user-controls, decimal

I've created a custom TextBox for Windows Application using C#.NET. It must accept decimal (floated point numbers) like 8.32 and 16.002.

I've constructed the following algorithm. It is accepting pure numbers only. I can't figure out how to make it accept float as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SmartTextBoxLib
{
    public partial class SmartTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public SmartTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `OnKeyPress` is the wrong event to use. What if someone would paste text in your text box with the mouse? You should simply use one of the existing masked text-boxes out there.

Comment: I'm aware of the existance of Masked Text-Boxes. I'm simply trying to reinvent the wheel for the sake of learning. So if you can suggest any alternative solution, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
    e.Handled = true;
base.OnKeyPress(e);
```

That allows digit characters or `.`.
You can make it `,` if you use that to seperate decimals.

---

Or, you could do this:

```
decimal value;
e.Handled = !decimal.TryParse((sender as TextBox).Text + e.KeyChar, out value);
base.OnKeyPress(e);
```

Comment: So `21.47..1.5..` is a valid number?

Comment: Thanks. With a little more modification like OnTextChanged event modifications I can finally make it work and define numbers like 21.47..1.5.. as invalid.

Comment: @Samik: Added an alternative.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's a better alternative to the one I was planning.

Comment: @Samik: Oops, I just realized that I need to add `+ e.KeyChar` part and edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, I've adjusted it accordingly. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown
```

instead, it will do this for you.

Comment: And call what event? Or check what condition?

Comment: @Samik: It has a `Decimal` property called `Value`.

Comment: I see. But If I wanted to modify a TextBox's behaviour into accepting decimal only, how should I rewrite my algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead Texbox control.

Defined the Mask property on MaskedTextBox control:

```
maskedTextBoxInstance.Mask = "99.000";
```